# Error while re building and running the android program in device with updated Android version(androidapi 15 rev1 to api 15 rev2)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, logcat, android-install-apk

**I did the following before i got issue:**
I ran a update in Android SDK Manager .It gave a list of updates to be installed which includes revision version for SDK platform-tools,SDK tools. After the download i couldnt install it automatically..So i installed manually as this was a issue with a lot of ppl.
Most of my apps in the workspace worked fine except a few.

**Actual issue**
 I could build the project successfully and i could also install it in the device.BUT WHEN I CLICK ON THE APP's UI i get error in the device as "..process has stopped unexpectedly .Please try again"
In logcat i get the following..

```
    04-16 19:01:30.131: I/PhoneGapLog(4042): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
    04-16 19:01:30.131: D/DroidGap(4042): DroidGap.onCreate()
    04-16 19:01:30.141: D/DroidGap(4042): DroidGap.loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
    04-16 19:01:30.141: D/DroidGap(4042): DroidGap: url=file:///android_asset/www/index.html baseUrl=file:///android_asset/www/
    04-16 19:01:30.141: D/DroidGap(4042): DroidGap.init()
    04-16 19:01:30.261: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(4042): Ignore this event
    04-16 19:01:30.311: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(4042): Ignore this event
    04-16 19:01:30.351: I/ActivityThread(4042): queueIdle
    04-16 19:01:30.351: V/ActivityThread(4042): Reporting idle of ActivityRecord{4a4a9448 token=android.os.BinderProxy@4a4a8ea8 {com.ingage.pocs.phonegap/com.ingage.pocs.phonegap.PhonegapIntegrationActivity}} finished=false
    04-16 19:01:30.351: W/ActivityNative(4042): send ACTIVITY_IDLE_TRANSACTION
    04-16 19:01:32.051: D/DroidGap(4042): DroidGap.startActivityForResult(intent,-1)
    04-16 19:01:32.091: W/dalvikvm(4042): VFY: unable to resolve static method 1761: Lcom/qualcomm/QCAR/QCAR;.requiresAlpha ()Z
    04-16 19:01:32.101: W/dalvikvm(4042): VFY: unable to resolve static method 1755: Lcom/qualcomm/QCAR/QCAR;.deinit ()V
    04-16 19:01:32.111: W/dalvikvm(4042): VFY: unable to resolve static method 1757: Lcom/qualcomm/QCAR/QCAR;.onPause ()V
    04-16 19:01:32.111: W/dalvikvm(4042): VFY: unable to resolve static method 1758: Lcom/qualcomm/QCAR/QCAR;.onResume ()V
    04-16 19:01:32.191: W/dalvikvm(4042): Exception Ljava/lang/NoClassDefFoundError; thrown during Lcom/ingage/pocs/phonegap/ImageTargets;.<clinit>
    04-16 19:01:32.201: W/dalvikvm(4042): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/ingage/pocs/phonegap/ImageTargets;)
    04-16 19:01:32.201: W/dalvikvm(4042): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400207d8)
    04-16 19:01:32.211: E/AndroidRuntime(4042): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    04-16 19:01:32.211: E/AndroidRuntime(4042): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    04-16 19:01:32.211: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    04-16 19:01:32.211: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
    04-16 19:01:32.211: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
    04-16 19:01:32.211: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2583)
    04-16 19:01:32.211: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2685)
    04-16 19:01:32.211: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:126)
    04-16 19:01:32.211: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2038)
    04-16 19:01:32.211: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    04-16 19:01:32.211: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    04-16 19:01:32.211: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
    04-16 19:01:32.211: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-16 19:01:32.211: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    04-16 19:01:32.211: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
    04-16 19:01:32.211: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    04-16 19:01:32.211: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    04-16 19:01:32.211: E/AndroidRuntime(4042): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.qualcomm.ar.pl.CameraPreview
    04-16 19:01:32.211: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native Method)
    04-16 19:01:32.211: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:448)
    04-16 19:01:32.211: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
    04-16 19:01:32.211: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at com.ingage.pocs.phonegap.ImageTargets.loadLibrary(ImageTargets.java:741)
    04-16 19:01:32.211: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at com.ingage.pocs.phonegap.ImageTargets.<clinit>(ImageTargets.java:128)
    04-16 19:01:32.211: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     ... 15 more
    04-16 19:01:32.211: E/AndroidRuntime(4042): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.qualcomm.ar.pl.CameraPreview in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.ingage.pocs.phonegap-1.apk]
    04-16 19:01:32.211: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
    04-16 19:01:32.211: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
    04-16 19:01:32.211: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
    04-16 19:01:32.211: E/AndroidRuntime(4042):     ... 20 more
```

Please guide me in this. i assume tht some of the class files arent being recognised..Any suggestion will do .Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

com.qualcomm.ar.pl.CameraPreview is from Vuforia library of Qualcomm. Just copy QCAR.jar to libs directory of your project.

Comment: You are right man.. found the issue and resolved it but forgot to post it here ..Wish you had replied ASAP :)Here you go

Comment: Note: don't forget to check the box in the "order and export" tab in the project properties too.

Comment: And don't forget to clean an rebuild all, eclipse do not automaticly detect such changes.

Comment: FYI I had the same problem and discovered under "order and export" the reference to the Qualcomm library was not checked.